# booting from qemu with self-made bare minimum OS

Tags: boot, virtualization, qemu, makefile, assembler

I wrote a minimal OS to boot from in nasm.

```
org 0x7C00 ;because the OS is loaded at address 0x7C00
bits 16 ;because we start in 16 bit mode

main:
    hlt

.halt
    jmp .halt

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0AA55h
```

The directory looks like this:

```
OsDev
--Makefile
--src/
----main.asm
--build/
----main.bin
----main.img
----main_floppy.img
```

and the Makefile looks like this:

```
ASM=nasm

SRC_DIR=src
BUILD_DIR=build

$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img: $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin
    cp $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin $(BUILD_DIR)/main.img
    truncate -s 1440k $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img

$(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin: $(SRC_DIR)/main.asm
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/main.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin
```

but I get this:

Screenshot of executing qemu-system-x86_64 -fda build/main_floppy.img

[image: screenshot of executing qemu-system-x86_64 -fda build/main_floppy.img]